# SQL Server database error and known information

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are many queries of restoring database in SQL Server - below are two:

Query #1

```
restore database database_name 
from disk = 'databaselocation+name'
```

Query #2

```
use master 
restore database database_name 
from disk = 'location'
```

What is the difference between simple restoration and master restoration?

Comment: You can't restore a database youre connected to (or anyone else is), therefore it's generally best to prefix the operation with `USE master;` to ensure that you aren't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between these two queries. However, management queries are created using the master database by default when created by the SSMS. It is better you also do this as these queries may change some information inside the master database.